# Dynamic programming technique

Tags: c++, recursion, dynamic-programming

I have this problem that I'm trying to solve:

> Given two numbers `K` and `S`, determine how many different values of `X`, `Y`, and `Z` exist such that `0 ≤ X, Y, Z ≤ K` and `X + Y + Z = S`.

Now, what I did is a recursive solution that tries every possible value for each one of the three digits.

```cpp
int count_sum(int k,int s,int sum=0,int limit=1,int counter=0)
{
    if(sum>s)
        return 0;

    if(sum==s)
        return 1;

    if(limit>3)
        return 0;

    for(int i=0; i<=k; i++)
    {
        if(i>s)
            break;
        counter=counter + count_sum(k,s,sum+i,limit+1);
    }
    return counter;
}
```

I know that this is `O(k^3)`, which is too high. I also know that there is a hack to solve this problem in `O(k^2)`. However, what I'm trying to do is optimize this solution with the technique of dynamic programming. I have tried to sketch a tree, but I couldn't figure out how to optimize it.

Comment: Dynamic programming would be overkill. You could do it in as single loop as O(k) and you can probably do it in O(1).

Comment: @lastchance
 Can you give a hint on how to do it in O(k) time?

Comment: What is `count_sum2`?

Comment: @Nelfeal
it's a mistake it should be count_sum

Comment: @codeer, let (say) Z loop from 0 to min(k,S). Then you can simply write down the number of X and Y values that add up to S-Z by working out the number of values that (say) X can take. (You end up using min and max a lot).

Comment: Just try to solve the subproblem where you only have one variable `X` (`X = S`), then add the second variable `Y` (`X + Y = S`), and finally add the third variable `Z`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `O(1)` solution, **but** this is **not using dynamic programming**. This simply uses a mathematical formula to directly compute the number of valid solutions in `O(1)` time

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int C(int n, int k) {
    if (k > n) return 0;
    int result = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
        result *= n - i + 1;
        result /= i;
    }
    return result;
}

int count_sum(int K, int S) {
    if (S > 3*K) return 0;
    int result = C(S+2, 2);
    result -= 3 * C(S-K-1, 2);
    result += 3 * C(S-2*K-2, 2);
    result -= C(S-3*K-3, 2);
    return result;
}

int main() {
    int K=10, S=15;
    //cin >> K >> S;
    cout << count_sum(K, S) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now **using dynamic programming**, I think the best approach will be limited only to `O(K^3)`. Unless there are only triplets as stated by [lastchance](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19767229/lastchance) then you can have an `O(k)`.

Using dynamic programming with `O(K^3)` time where its running time grows cubically with the size of the input:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int count_sum(int K, int S, int n, vector<vector<vector<int>>>& dp) {
    if (n == 1) return (K == S);
    if (dp[n][K][S] != -1) return dp[n][K][S];
    int result = 0;
    for (int X = max(S - (n-1) * K, 0); X <= min(K, S); X++) {
        result += count_sum(K, S - X, n - 1, dp);
    }
    dp[n][K][S] = result;
    return result;
}

int main() {
    int K = 10, S = 15, n = 3;
    vector<vector<vector<int>>> dp(n+1, vector<vector<int>>(K+1, vector<int>(S+1, -1)));
    cout << count_sum(K, S, n, dp) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, as long as there are only triplets, here's an O(k) solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int countTriples( int k, int S )
{
   int result = 0;
   for ( int Z = max( S - 2 * k, 0 ); Z <= min( k, S ); Z++ ) result += min( k, S - Z ) - max( S - Z - k, 0 ) + 1;
   return result;
}

int main()
{
   int k, S;
   cout << "Enter k and S: ";   cin >> k >> S;
   cout << countTriples( k, S );
}
```

Some output:

```
Enter k and S: 3 5
12
```

corresponding to collection

```
2 3 0
3 2 0

1 3 1
2 2 1
3 1 1

0 3 2
1 2 2
2 1 2
3 0 2

0 2 3
1 1 3
2 0 3
```

**EDIT: Generalisation**

You should be able to generalise this (by recursion) to n-tuples such that

```
0<=X1,X2,...,Xn<=k and X1+X2+...+Xn=S
```

The method is O(k<sup>(n-2)</sup>) since the base cases n=1 and n=2 are O(1).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int countTuples( int k, int S, int n )
{
   if      ( n == 1 ) return ( k >= S );
   else if ( n == 2 ) return 2 * k >= S ? min( k, S ) - max( S - k, 0 ) + 1 : 0;

   int result = 0;
   for ( int X = max( S - (n-1) * k, 0 ); X <= min( k, S ); X++ ) result += countTuples( k, S - X, n - 1 );
   return result;
}

int main()
{
   int k, S, n;
   cout << "Enter k, S, n: ";   cin >> k >> S >> n;
   cout << countTuples( k, S, n );
}
```

Output:

```
Enter k, S, n: 3 5 3
12
```